# Does Chrome run on Debian kFreeBSD?

Tags: debian, freebsd, chrome

I know that some Linux applications run on FreeBSD. All the more so, they should run on Debian kFreeBSD (since it only uses a FreeBSD kernel while Linux userspace).

Does Google Chrome (not Chromium, as I need flash) run on Debian kFreeBSD?

Comment: a) What makes you think Chromium doesn't do Flash? (See [this recent issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173790) on getting it to work)  b) Please don't [cross post](http://superuser.com/questions/545235/can-i-run-chrome-on-debian-kfreebsd), trust in the moderators to move your post if it's not in the SE site best suited for your question.  c) Anyway, [Debian's `chromium` package is not available for kFreeBSD](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=chromium) but Chromium seems to run on FreeBSD.

Comment: I'd guess it does work, Chrome (as an application not too intimately tied to the kernel) shouldn't use any Linux funkiness. Does it run on *BSD at all? What do the release notes say? But who knows... In any case, it is _much_ faster (and futhermore _guaranteed_ to give the correct answer) than waiting for a couple of days, and then sifting though a lot of posts by random ignorants like myself, some outdated experimental results, mixed in with a few comments by ones in the know, is to try it yourself!